# SQL IF STATEMENT

Tags: sql

I am writing a code to get rankings from a database, put it in the table and order by it. The issue is that I'm joining few tables and some players who take part in a tournament are not even in rankings table (i have a different table for a list of players). For now, players who don't have rank have a null value and are displayed like that. That could be ok, but I need to order players by rank. And it looks like this:[image]

The question is - is there if statement that will make the empty value in, for example, 5000 and players without ranking would be displayed in the bottom of the table. Thanks in advance!

My code:

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    p1.surname AS 'p1surname', 
    p1.name AS 'p1name', 
    p2.surname AS 'p2surname', 
    p2.name AS 'p2name', 
    m1.rank AS 'm1rank', 
    m2.rank AS 'm2rank'
    CASE
       WHEN m1rank is NULL 
          THEN m1rank = '5000' 
    END,
    CASE 
       WHEN m2rank is NULL 
          THEN m2rank = '5000' 
    END
FROM 
    alists_lv lv 
JOIN 
    players p1 ON lv.player1_id = p1.id
JOIN 
    players p2 ON lv.player2_id = p2.id
LEFT JOIN 
    womensranking m1 ON lv.player1_id = m1.id
LEFT JOIN 
    womensranking m2 ON lv.player2_id = m2.id  
WHERE 
    tournament_id = '$id' AND p1.gender = 'F'
ORDER BY 
    (m1rank + m2rank)
```

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you have is fine, but you need to add else statements to your case statements:

> CASE WHEN m1.rank is NULL THEN m1.rank = '5000' else m1.rank END,
>
> CASE WHEN m2.rank is NULL THEN m2.rank = '5000' else m2.rank END

And then add those same case statements to your order by clause. Or you can alias those case statements and put those aliases in your order by clause.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Using `COALESCE`

```
SELECT *, p1.surname AS 'p1surname', 
p1.name AS 'p1name', 
p2.surname AS 'p2surname', 
p2.name AS 'p2name', 
COALESCE(m1.rank, '5000') AS 'm1rank', 
COALESCE(m2.rank, '5000') AS 'm2rank'
```

Answer (score 0):

If null rank order them last, otherwise order by rank. So something like:

```
  ORDER BY CASE WHEN m1rank IS NULL OR m2rank IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
             m1rank, 
             m2rank
```